# Qt slot method (which is another class) not firing when emiting the signal

Tags: c++, visual-studio, qt

I know this question asked many times but still confused and cannot find a solution.

I have a MainWindow and a class.

In my class I have a signal which I emit in the method call.

Problem: Slot method is not firing.

Here is my code.

BWorker.h

```
#pragma once

#include <QObject>

class BWorker : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    BWorker(QObject *parent);
    ~BWorker();
    void doSomething();

signals:
    void signalSomething();

};
```

BWorker.cpp

```
#include "BWorker.h"

BWorker::BWorker(QObject *parent)
    : QObject(parent)
{
}

BWorker::~BWorker()
{
}

void BWorker::doSomething() 
{
    emit signalSomething();
}
```

QtGuiApplication1.h

```
#pragma once

#include <QtWidgets/QMainWindow>
#include "ui_QtGuiApplication1.h"

class QtGuiApplication1 : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    QtGuiApplication1(QWidget *parent = Q_NULLPTR);

public slots:
    void workDone();

private:
    Ui::QtGuiApplication1Class ui;
};
```

QtGuiApplication1.cpp

```
#include "QtGuiApplication1.h"
#include "BWorker.h"

QtGuiApplication1::QtGuiApplication1(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
{
    ui.setupUi(this);

    BWorker bworker(this);

    connect(&bworker, SIGNAL(bworker.signalSomething), this, SLOT(workDone()));

    bworker.doSomething();

}

void QtGuiApplication1::workDone() {

}
```

Comment: I believe you are missing parenthesis inside the `SIGNAL` part. If you had used the [new syntax](https://wiki.qt.io/New_Signal_Slot_Syntax) this would not have happened.

Comment: Be sure to check the stdout output of your program -- if the connect() call fails, Qt often prints a message describing why to stdout.  If you see a message there you'll know that is why your slot method isn't being called.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner what should I print out exactly to see the problem? There is no any error.

Comment: @ggdev add to top of your main():  AllocConsole(); freopen("conout$, "w", stdout); freopen("conout$", "w", stderr);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
SIGNAL(bworker.signalSomething)
```

This is not valid and you should see a message in terminal saying that there is no such signal. The correct syntax for your case would be:

```
SIGNAL(signalSomething())
```

Comment: I assume since you accepted this answer that your comment was wrong??

Comment: Yes I removed it :)

Answer (score 0):

Please post your code by copy-pasting it. Do not edit the code: The problem could be emerged *from where you edited*.

The code of mine worked fine.

mainwindow.h:

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

public slots:
    void workDone();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

mainwindow.cpp:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <QDebug>
#include "worker.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    Worker worker(this);
    connect(&worker, SIGNAL(signalSomething()), this, SLOT(workDone()));
    //connect(&worker, &Worker::signalSomething, this, &MainWindow::workDone);
    worker.doSomething();
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::workDone()
{
    qDebug() << "Done.";
}
```

worker.h:

```
#ifndef WORKER_H
#define WORKER_H

#include <QObject>

class Worker : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit Worker(QObject *parent = 0);
    void doSomething();
signals:
    void signalSomething();
public slots:
};

#endif // WORKER_H
```

worker.cpp:

```
#include "worker.h"

Worker::Worker(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent)
{

}

void Worker::doSomething()
{
    emit signalSomething();
}
```

Application Output:

```
Debugging starts
Done.
Debugging has finished
```

Printed out "Done." means the codes are working.